# False Positive? Cannot insert duplicate Key Row (EF6)

Tags: sql-server, wcf, entity-framework-6

I have a client application sending data to a WCF service which uses EF6 to manage an MS SQL Database. The Database has a table which has a Unique Index on column UHash. When inserting a new record with a new unique hash - It fails with an error about not being able to add the hash because it is already present.

The data being sent to the table is this:

> UHash:
>   "7B2AF233DCCE5527F492C1E1070CAA9159ECD2B6BFAEFB585A470632C11C55929BD0721857AAEB82AE91E68D7F50421599273B916AD5E026FBC464F7851301E8"

However, the error reports this key!

> Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.U' with unique index
>   'UniqueHashes'. The duplicate key value is
>   (6A95EC825B121E2BA9E59EA8BD14613115FA3C344ECC01C1CD77AE072E3C70C2CE506B47D2D0DA17637D81E921D1EF367411EDD1077402D09D511C1371176DDF).
>       The statement has been terminated.

This key does exist but has NOTHING to do with the data being sent to the MS SQL Server.

**Any ideas at all why this would be happening?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22209734/cannot-insert-duplicate-key-row-in-object-with-unique-index

Comment: @mohan111 you didn't read the question. The Duplicate Key is not being sent to the database an entirely different key is being sent - but the server is reporting it as a duplicate.

Comment: Are there triggers on the table by chance?

Comment: Do an integrity check of the index. (DBCC)

Comment: @GertArnold Integrity Check is ok

Comment: I would capture the statement via profiler so you can repro it in ssms.  You may have additional constraints, or columns or other DML not accounted for.